# zoom in on a uiwebview by taping?

Tags: iphone, pdf, sdk, uiwebview, zooming

In Safair mobile you can zoom in by double taping if you have a html page that you display.
But if you use a uiwebview and display an image or pdf file you have to pinch open to zoom.

My question is: what do I have to do to get double tap to work when displaying an image or pdf file i a uiwebview?

Can you make the uiwebview a sub view under a uiscrollview, will you then be able to double tap an zoom?
And how would you do that?

Comment: Well I suppose you could attach one piece of tape to the left of the UIWebView, then another one on the right, and then pull the two apart.

Answer (score 1):

What a double tap in Mobile Safari really does is *focus* on the content. It will find the `div` or section on the web page that you tapped on and then zoom to focus. It is not simply 'double tap to zoom'.

Answer (score 0):

To get double tap from UIWebview u need to subclass the UIWindow and use the method,

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"tap detect");
    NSArray *allTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    UIView *touchView = [touch view];

    if (touchView && [touchView isDescendantOfView:urWebview]) {
        //
        // touchesBegan
        //
               if(touch.tapCount==2){
                     //
                // doubletap
                //
               }
       }
}
```